# Does Apple Care+ provide International Warranty on iPhones?

Tags: iphone, warranty, applecare

If I buy an iPhone 8 from USA with AppleCare+ warranty plan, then would the warranty hold in India?

Comment: [Here's the AppleCare+ legal info](https://www.apple.com/legal/sales-support/applecare/applecareplus/docs/applecareplusnaen.html) for an iPhone sold in the US.  Apple occasionally changes their warranty terms so you'll need to read it to verify what's covered.

Comment: It doesn't really make economic or legal sense for a company to allow a warranty written in one country to carry over to another country.

Comment: Asking for the first-hand experience would make this question extremely more useful for other readers. Would you mind editing the question to reflect that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Be careful but also you might be fine in many / most cases. Also, AppleCare and AppleCare Plus are not warranties but service programs.

- https://www.apple.com/legal/sales-support/applecare/applecareplus/

Warranty is certainly one very good form of legal consumer protection. This body of law affects and extends and restricts business and you only get this protection from the country of purchase and generally for less often from the country of import to.

- [Is Apple's warranty international?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/30/is-apples-warranty-international)

Just as with warranty, there is language that allows Apple to restrict service to the country of sale:

> Apple may restrict Hardware Service and ADH Services to the country where the Covered Equipment was originally purchased.